# Method parameters with same type

Tags: java, methods

I am wondering what is the best practices to write method that takes at least three parameters of the same type. The problem is that you can mix up parameters when using such method. For example

```
method(int userId, int productId, int weight, int price)
```

The only solution I see is to use some holder class(maybe with builder pattern used) and passing it as method parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best practice is to use clear parameter names (and possibly clarifying them in the Javadoc). If there are too many parameters, a separate object is better.

If the caller of the method can't distinguish between different (well named) parameters, then maybe he shouldn't be calling the method in the first place.

Comment: Plus with modern IDEs showing code completion (Eclipse shows parameter names) it seems impossible to mix them up, unless you are determined to do so.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your exact situation, [Introduce Parameter Object](http://refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html) may be a relevant refactoring option.

[More explanations here](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/introduce-parameter-object), from which I quote the below (**emphasis** mine):

> Often you see a particular group of parameters that tend to be passed
>   together. Several methods may use this group, either on one class or
>   in several classes. Such a group of classes is a data clump and can be
>   replaced with an object that carries all of this data. It is
>   worthwhile to turn these parameters into objects just to group the
>   data together. This refactoring is useful because it **reduces the size
>   of the parameter lists, and long parameter lists are hard to
>   understand.** The defined accessors on the new object also make the code
>   more consistent, which again makes it easier to understand and modify.

Comment: I know… to me it’s common knowledge (too), but it seems to be a new thing to the questioner so it’s worth adding some more word. Now…+1

Answer (score 0):

For me i think the best practice is to use Data class (java bean ) and but your parameter there with a will named standard and then you use this data class object as parameter.

The disadvantage of this approach is that you are increasing coupling in you system .

Answer (score -4):

You can use variable arguments concept in this case.

```
method(int… ids){
    userid = ids[0];
    productid = ids[1];
}
```

Comment: I just wanted to suggest him that if arguments are of similar type, then var-args can be used. That's what I wanted to say!